# Write a program in C to print armstrong numbers from 1 to 10000

Tags: c

This is the program I wrote. I get a blank output when I execute it. Can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
int a, b = 0, s, n;
printf("The armstrong numbers are-");
for (n = 1; n <= 10000; n++) {
  s = n;
  while (n > 0) {
    a = n % 10;
    b = b + a * a * a;
    n = n / 10;
  }
  if (b == s)
    printf("%d ", s);
}
}
```

Comment: Walk through your loop with n=1. Do you see an issue?

Comment: n will be changed because of `n = n / 10`.

Comment: The for loop variant is n, and you are modifying n in the while loop. That is the problem.

Comment: @SumitTrehan I tried modifying s instead of n and now it just prints "The armstrong numbers are-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested Don't change `n` inside the for loop as your loop depends on the variable `n`. you have to set `b` back to `0` for each iteration.

Your program is not very much readable as others might not understand what does `a`,`b`,`n` and `s` mean. So, always use meaningful variable names like this: (see comments for more description)

```
#include<stdio.h>  

int main(void)      //correct signature for main function
{
    int digit;  //instead of a
    int sum=0;  //instead of b
    int number; //instead of n

    printf("The armstrong numbers are-");

    for(number = 1; number <= 10000; number++)
    { 
        int temporary = number; //temporary integer to store number value
        sum = 0;                //sum must be reset to 0 at the start of each iteration

        while(temporary > 0) 
        {
            digit = temporary % 10; 
            sum = sum + (digit * digit * digit); 
            temporary = temporary / 10;
        }

        if(sum == number)        //if sum obtained == number, print it! 
            printf("%d ",number); 
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
The armstrong numbers are-1 153 370 371 407
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I get it it now.

Comment: @Cherubim 1634 is also an armstrong number. your logic works fine with the only three digit number.

Comment: i have a doubt here, how 1634 is an armstrong number? as far as I know 1634=1*1*1+6*6*6+3*3*3+4*4*4 =1+216+27+64 = 308. What is the logic here could you explain? @vinit

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't change n inside the for loop.
2. you have to set b back to 0 for every n.

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed that the value of b has to be reset

Answer (score 0):

The loop variable n was getting modified in the loop. So use the temporary variable s to do the inner while loop. And variable b must be initialized to zero every time you check for a new number.  It's a good practice to define the variable within block that you use rather than defining everything globally or in the start of main.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("The armstrong numbers are-");

    for (n=1; n<=10000; n++) {
        int a, b=0, s=n;
        while (s > 0) {
            a = s % 10;
            b = b + (a*a*a);
            s = s / 10;
        }

        if (b == n)
            printf("%d ", n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have a habit of declaring everything at the start.  Guess i need to change that.

Comment: @TitikhyuDixit accept this as answer